# When ordering SAS replacement drive, does the hot swappable enclosure matter?

Tags: hard-drive, sas, hotswap, hardware

I have a dell PowerEdge and need to replace one of the SAS drives in it.   I noticed the supplier I order from does not sell a specific "DELL" SAS replacement drive, but they have what appear to be compatible SAS (15000rpm/146gb/SAS) drives.

The problem is, they are branded "IBM", "HP" and "Fujtisu".   Each of them appear to have their own type of hot swappable mechanism attached in the picture.

I am ASSUMING that's OK and I would simple unscrew the drive from that enclosure and put it in to my Dell hot swap tray?

Comment: That is what you would typically do but you should probably verify that the drive is supported in your server. You should be able to get that information from Dell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the logistics go, that will work. The hot swap enclosure is just an enclosure for a standard 3.5 inch drive. However there was a time when Dell machines would only recognise, or allow you to use Dell branded disks. I believe Dell updated their firmware in most places to make that not the case, but you may want to make sure that your firmware is up to date.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't your Dell still under warranty? If it isn't, you can replace the disk with another model and reuse the hotswap drive carrier.